# How would i access the object's of a website through python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

Okay, as far as i know those "Objects" are only accessible through console but if it's accessible through the console why wouldn't it be accessible through python? I haven't tried anything yet because i have literal NO idea of what could i do..... Any help would be appreciated, is it possible to get the object through requests? Also i would appreciate the name that those "Objects" of the websites are called :D Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout selenium python
it has methods for the execution of scripts and finding DOM elements

driver.execute_script("some javascript code here");

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("www.google.co.in") 
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByXpath('//input[@name='q']')
```

Another method would be to Use beautifulsoup(BS4)

also, you can use scrappy. it's quite powerful but has a major style that needs to be followed and less freedom.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i am looking for a faster solution...

Comment: I have updated the comment with what else you can use for scrapping. checkout this repo of I had done while learning to scrap. it scrapes two websites that are ok with being scrapped. 
https://github.com/akashgkrishnan/pythonScrappy